# Get Preloaded Data from Azure Mobile Service Android

Tags: android, azure, android-activity, azure-mobile-services

I want to get all the preloaded datas available on my Windows Azure Mobile Service.

Let's just say I have a Table named **RV_RoadData** and inside the Table, there is a Column for StudentIDs as Integer and Text as String. There are 50 Values loaded so far.

I just want to save those values in my ArrayList and then use for future references. This is what I tried:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

TextView textView;
Button btn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    fechFromAzure();
}


//this is the only method talking to azure.
//here, no threads/asynctasks are used. So, fetching operation should    not take more
//than 5 seconds. Otherwise, app will freeze.
private void fechFromAzure(){
    try {
    //initialize the mobile service
    MobileServiceClient mClient = new MobileServiceClient(
            "https://******.azure-mobile.net/",
            "*******************************",
            this
    );

    //get the todo-item table
    MobileServiceTable<RV_RoadData> RV_RoadData_Table = mClient.getTable(RV_RoadData.class);

    //select all items from todo-item
    List<RV_RoadData> itemList = RV_RoadData_Table.where().execute().get();

    //set text of first and only one todo-item to textview
    textView.setText(itemList.get(0).Text);

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

class RV_RoadData {
    public String Id;
    public String Text;
    }
}
```

But is seems to give me unwanted Exception. I really don't know where I am doing wrong. Please help to solve this problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try following the pattern in this tutorial, which uses an adapter to store a list of data.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-android-get-started-data/

It also returns a MobileServicesList instead of a List. The data in its database is also very similar to yours, so it should be very easy to adapt it.

Comment: This is the Simply toDoList in Action. I was wanting something different.

Comment: Also, if you want a list, an adapter is one way to do it, but the code you show is just displaying a single item.